# Can't add any principals in Kerberos

Tags: debian, kerberos

I recently botched a Kerberos install and have been trying to follow the walkthrough [here](http://www.rjsystems.nl/en/2100-d6-kerberos-openldap-provider.php).

However, now I've reached an awkward impasse and cannot add any principals. 
Using kadmin.local I receive the message:

```
add_principal: Principal add failed: Insufficient access while creating "admin@
```

The ACL contains:

```
*/admin *
admin *
```

More specifically, I see:

```
root@server:/home/server# kadmin.local
Authenticating as principal root/admin@SERVER.LAN with password.
kadmin.local:  addprinc admin
WARNING: no policy specified for admin@SERVER.LAN; defaulting to no policy
Enter password for principal "admin@SERVER.LAN":
Re-enter password for principal "admin@SERVER.LAN":
add_principal: Principal add failed: Insufficient access while creating "admin@SERVER.LAN".
kadmin.local:
```

Comment: Are you running `kadmin.local` as root? If not, do so.

Comment: I was. That's why it was so odd I couldn't add a principal.

Comment: Working through this: http://techpubs.spinlocksolutions.com/dklar/kerberos.html#krb-install instead - it seems that there's something odd with the setup. (In the previous not working setup) The acl file isn't being called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite the question is old:
Try to add a principal with realm, even if you have a default realm configured. I had similar issues, and using a realm solved them for me.
And admin user is not very wise, use rather root/admin or similar:
root/admin@[YOUR REALM]

Comment: This answer fails to explain how. This will still result in Insufficient Access.